# Find hidden objects in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I have an Illustrator file with thousands of objects. I want to search the Layers pane to find hidden objects (e.g., move to the next hidden object in the pane). I do not want to show all objects, don't want to search for text in hidden objects, I want to know what objects (and layers) are currently hidden.

Thanks!

Comment: Theres currently no functionality to filter items in a gui. Use scripting to traverse the scene and record ones that qre hidden

Comment: Expand the layer in the Layers Panel and find the objects without the eye icon??

Comment: @Scott, there are **thousands** of objects...

Comment: Then as Joojaa points out, you'd need scripting.

Comment: Just spitballing... Unhide all, cut, new layer, paste in front or back. All formerly hidden objects are now on their own separate layer in the exact same position. To hide them again, just hide the layer. No need to search or find anything.